# C++ doesn't see the copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

I'm working on a small vector class for my project and basically I wan't to be able to construct a vector from any kind of number. even if they're all different (such as Vector3(float, int, unsigned)). However, I've encountered a small problem and I got lost in those templates and their order. And now my arithmetic operators aren't working properly.

This is the code for the vector class:

```
#include "Defines.hpp" // Typedefs for the fundamental types...
#include "Math/Base.hpp" // Various numerical functions...

template<class T, class Enable = void>
class Vector3;

template<class T>
class Vector3<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value >::type>
{
public:
    Vector3()
        : X(0), Y(0), Z(0)
    {

    }

//    explicit Vector3(T s)
//        : X(s), Y(s), Z(s)
//    {
//
//    }

    template <class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit Vector3(U s)
        : X(getBounded<T>(s)), Y(getBounded<T>(s)), Z(getBounded<T>(s))
    {

    }

//    explicit Vector3(T x, T y, T z)
//        : X(x), Y(y), Z(z)
//    {
//
//    }

    template <class U1, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U1>::value>::type* = nullptr
            , class U2, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U2>::value>::type* = nullptr
            , class U3, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U3>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit Vector3(U1 x, U2 y, U3 z)
        : X(getBounded<T>(x)), Y(getBounded<T>(y)), Z(getBounded<T>(z))
    {

    }

//    explicit Vector3(const Vector3<T>& v)
//        : X(v.X), Y(v.Y), Z(v.Z)
//    {
//
//    }

    template <class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    explicit Vector3(const Vector3<U>& v)
        : X(getBounded<T>(v.X)), Y(getBounded<T>(v.Y)), Z(getBounded<T>(v.Z))
    {

    }

    explicit Vector3(Vector3<T>&& v)
        : X(v.X), Y(v.Y), Z(v.Z)
    {

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~Vector3()
    {

    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Vector3<T> & operator= (const Vector3<T> & v)
    {
        this->X = v.X;
        this->Y = v.Y;
        this->Z = v.Z;
        return *this;
    }
    Vector3<T> & operator= (Vector3<T>&& v)
    {
        this->X = v.X;
        this->Y = v.Y;
        this->Z = v.Z;
        return *this;
    }
    template <class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    Vector3<T> & operator= (const Vector3<U> & v)
    {
        this->X = getBounded<T>(v.X);
        this->Y = getBounded<T>(v.Y);
        this->Z = getBounded<T>(v.Z);
        return *this;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    T X, Y, Z;
};

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr
        , class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
Vector3<T> operator+ (const Vector3<T> & v, const U & s)
{
    return Vector3<T>(v.X + getBounded<T>(s), v.Y + getBounded<T>(s), v.Z + getBounded<T>(s));
}

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr
        , class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
Vector3<T> operator+ (const T & s, const Vector3<U> & v)
{
    return Vector3<T>(s + getBounded<T>(v.X), s + getBounded<T>(v.Y), s + getBounded<T>(v.Z));
}

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr
        , class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
Vector3<T> operator+ (const Vector3<T> & va, const Vector3<U> & vb)
{
    return Vector3<T>(va.X + getBounded<T>(vb.X), va.Y + getBounded<T>(vb.Y), va.Z + getBounded<T>(vb.Z));
}

typedef Vector3< Int8 >    Vector3C;
typedef Vector3< Uint8 >   Vector3UC;
typedef Vector3< Int16 >   Vector3S;
typedef Vector3< Uint16 >  Vector3US;
typedef Vector3< Int32 >   Vector3I;
typedef Vector3< Uint32 >  Vector3UI;
typedef Vector3< Int64 >   Vector3L;
typedef Vector3< Uint64 >  Vector3UL;
typedef Vector3< Float32 > Vector3F;
typedef Vector3< Float64 > Vector3D;
```

With the current constructors commented out I get this error:

```
||=== Build: Win32 Release in Sandbox (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
..\source\Math\Vector3.hpp||In instantiation of 'Vector3<T> operator+(const Vector3<T>&, const Vector3<U>&) [with T = int; typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value>::type* <anonymous> = 0u; U = unsigned char; typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type* <anonymous> = 0u]':|
(...)\sandbox\main.cpp|#|required from here|
..\source\Math\Vector3.hpp|#|error: use of deleted function 'constexpr Vector3<int>::Vector3(const Vector3<int>&)'|
..\source\Math\Vector3.hpp|#|note: 'constexpr Vector3<int>::Vector3(const Vector3<int>&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'Vector3<int>' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

When I uncomment the required copy constructor in the error message then I get another error and so on.

Everything works until I reach the overloaded arithmetic operators:

```
Vector3I v1(123343, -2143423, 12.35352f);

printf("%i, %i, %i\n", v1.X, v1.Y, v1.Z);

Vector3UC v2(v1);

printf("%i, %i, %i\n", v2.X, v2.Y, v2.Z);

v2 = v1 + v2; // If I comment this out then it works.

printf("%i, %i, %i\n", v2.X, v2.Y, v2.Z);
```

Comment: I don't see a question.  Just a lot of code and a statement that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I don't see any copy constructor declared in `Vector3`.

Comment: This is your 30th question.  Have you never read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?  I could read through your code and find your problem, but it would be useless for future visitors.  Eliminate code until you get a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.  I can tell you 99% of your code is completely unrelated to your problem.  Quite possibly when you have reduced it to a minimal case, you'll see your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the declaration of vector3:

```
explicit Vector3(Vector3<T>&& v)
    : X(v.X), Y(v.Y), Z(v.Z)
{

}
```

You made the move constructor of Vector3 explicit, which means it can't be called implicitly.

As this sentence:

```
v2 = v1 + v2;
```

v1 + v2 will create a temporary object, and an implicit move constructor is needed here to construct the v2 on the left, this is how the compile error happened, please remove the  explicit key word in the move constructor.

A good example of move constructor is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer#movesemantics)